# Unittest Traceback Issue

Tags: python, list, unit-testing

I am having issues with my below code my a Unittest. I keep receiving a traceback and I do not know why.My program is running fine except for the Unittests that I created.For the unittest I just want to make sure that the first word in being returned in all_first_words.  Any help would be great.

Traceback:

```
  File "final_project.py", line 219, in test_first_words_list
    self.assertEqual(Song().firstwords(["hello world"]),["hello"])
  File "final_project.py", line 69, in firstwords
    first_word = track.trackName.partition(' ')[0] # split the string at the first word, isolates the first word in the title
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'trackName'




import unittest
class TestSong(unittest.TestCase):
def test_first_words_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(Song().firstwords(["hello world"]),["hello"])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Code Being Tested:

```
def firstwords(self,large_song_list): # method that takes the first word of each song title and creates a list containing that first word 
        all_first_words = [] # create an empty list 
        for track in large_song_list: 
            first_word = track.trackName.partition(' ')[0] # split the string at the first word, isolates the first word in the title 
            all_first_words.append(first_word)
        return all_first_words
```

Comment: You are passing in a list of strings.  strings do not have a `trackName` attribute.  Which is exactly what the error message says....

Answer (score 1):

The *track* variable is a **string**.

You can simplify your code like this:

```
def firstwords(self,large_song_list):
    """ method that takes the first word of each song title
    and creates a list containing that first word
    """
    all_first_words = [] # create an empty list 
    for track in large_song_list: 
        first_word = track.partition(' ')[0] # split the string at the first word, isolates the first word in the title 
        all_first_words.append(first_word)
    return all_first_words
```

Note: this can be accomplish in one line with a [comprehension list](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
    all_first_words = [track.partition(' ')[0] for track in large_song_list]
```